# Reversible chain tensioner

Tags: chain

Does anyone have any good experience with reversible chain tensioner designs? Power of transmission is 28 kW and torque on input sprocket is around 10 kNm. Sprockets are positioned verticaly with smaller on the bottom position.

All I can find looks very weak (for example: https://rosta.com/chain-drive-tensioning/) and I would like to design something stronger, mostly because it just looks stronger (user quirks).

One solution I was thinking about was to use two sprockets, maybe closer to the smaller one and move them together with threaded rod or something similar.

[image]

Comment: Move the axles apart with a hydraulic ram - check out how Caterpillar keep tracks under tension...

Comment: what's the distance between the shafts? Maybe you are better off with one or two additional gears, to split the distance.

Comment: Try [these](https://www.mcmaster.com/chain-tensioners/) [McMaster Carr] for inspiration?

Comment: @Solar Mike, I can't do that because top sprocket is fixed on shaft, which has its location fixed with bearings. Bottom sprocket is also fixed because it's mounted on a shaft that is located in a gearbox. Design is made in such way, that the gearbox is also fixed and can't move up and down.

Comment: @NMech, distance between shafts is 1350 mm. I will think about more chain gears, but I leaning more to the option to get the bottom shaft with the gearbox moving up and down, to set the tension. It will bring some changes with it, but what can we do...

Comment: Hi everyone. Just to bring some information back. I designed tensioning system with gearbox attached to hinged platform, so that the distance between axles can be adjusted. I also added two spring tensioners on both chain strands so they help eliminate elongaion during the running, when you can't adjust the hinged platform. When everything is detailed and finished, I will post here. Maybe someone can use it in the future...